# Reduce the number of authors in references

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style, apacite

I would like more than 3 author citations to show up using *et al.* rather than with full names.

Example:
* were death cases because of the autopsy Rao, Sood, Pathak,
and Dongre (2014).*

I need to show >3 author names like (Rao et al., (2014))

**Code**

```
\documentclass{UnimasThesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{enumerate}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,columns=fullflexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{NavyBlue},
commentstyle=\itshape\color{PaleVioletRed4},
frame=single,framesep=6pt,
framexleftmargin=6pt,framexrightmargin=6pt,
xleftmargin=12pt,xrightmargin=12pt,
breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true}


\title{AUTOMATIC SEGMENTATION OF CARDIAC MAGNETIC RESONANCE IMAGES FOR OEDEMA ASSESSMENT}
\author{Amajd Khan}
\faculty{Faculty of Computer Science and Information Technology }
\facultyColour{6c7a8c} %% 6-digit RGB hexadecimal code 
\submissionyear{2017}
\degreetype{Doctor of Philosophy\\(Computer Science)}

% If using APA bibliography style

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter



\mainmatter
% Each chapter from a separate file
\input{chap1-Introduction}

% references are listed in refs.bib
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

**`.bib` file**

```
    @article{rao:2014,
    title={Causes of Sudden Cardiac Death on Autopsy Findings; a Four-Year Report},
    author={Rao, Dinesh., and Sood, Divya., and Pathak, P., and Dongre, Sudhir, D},
    journal={Journal  of Emergency-An Academic Emergency Medicine},
    volume={2},
    number={1},
    pages={12-17},
    year={2014}
}
```